# ReactJS Using child props in parent class

Tags: reactjs, onclick, state, react-props

I have a parent class which is using its child to render some Buttons out of the array 'days'. This is working fine so far. I use the handler to pass the handleClick() to the child. This also worked, without the if statement I get the return in console. What is wrong with my code or thinking for the if statement.
It should reply 'Hi 1' if I click on the Button with value days[0] = 1.

Parent:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      days: [1,2,3]
    }

  }

  handleClick() {
      if(this.props.value === 1) {
      return console.log('Hi 1')
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div>
            {this.state.days.map(item => <ButtonDays handler={ () => this.handleClick()} key={item} value={item} />)}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child:

```
export default class ButtonDays extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.props.handler}>{this.props.value}</Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood something... you want that when the child button gets clicked, it basically console.log `Hi ` and its value from the parent?

Comment: `this.props.value` is `undefined` in `Parent` class

Answer (score 0):

In the following part of your parent component

```
handleClick() {
  if(this.props.value === 1) {
    return console.log('Hi 1')
  }
}
```

You are checking for a props named `value`, but this props is only defined in your child component.

What you should do instead is passing the clicked value as a param of the `handler` function.

```
<Button onClick={() => this.props.handler(this.props.value)}>{this.props.value}</Button>
```

And then in your parent component:

```
handleClick(value) {
  if(value === 1) {
    return console.log('Hi 1')
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arnaud, 

thanks a lot for your answer and it seems like we are / I am definitly on the rigth way!

If I do it like you suggest the 'Hi 1' is still not printed.
But if I set handleClick() to
`handleClick(value) {
   return console.log({value})
  }', 

I get back: Object { value: undefined }

Comment: Actually I did not notice that your were returning the result of `console.log`. You can remove the return and just keep the `console.log("Hi 1")`